# Moving files to a folder, Error 13 Type mismatch

Tags: vba, file, fso

I want to move files to created folders. I got a mismatch error every time.

The aim is to create a folder named after the file prefix if it doesn't exist and copy the file to that folder.

I get

> mismatch error

```vb
Sub loopf()
    Dim AcceptedPrefixes As Object
    Set AcceptedPrefixes = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim PrefixRange As Range
    Set PrefixRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B2:B368")
    
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In PrefixRange.Cells
        If Cell <> "" And Not AcceptedPrefixes.exists(Cell.Value) Then
            AcceptedPrefixes.Add CStr(Cell.Value), 0
        End If
    Next

    Dim Directory As String
    Directory = "C:\TEST\"
    
    Dim fsoFSO
    Set fsoFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Dim filen As Variant
    filen = Dir(Directory)
    While filen <> ""
        Dim FilePrefix As String
        FilePrefix = "" & (Split(filen, "_")(0)) & ""
        
        If Not AcceptedPrefixes.exists(FilePrefix) Then
            Kill Directory & filen
        Else
            If fsoFSO.FolderExists("C:\TEST\" & FilePrefix) Then
                'DO NOTHING
           
            Else: fsoFSO.CreateFolder ("C:\TEST\" & FilePrefix) 'ELSE CREATE A FOLDER

                ' HERE i WANT TO MOVE THE FILES TO TRHE CREATED FOLDER OR EXISTING FOLDER
                fso.MoveFile "C:\TEST\ & Filen", "C:\TEST\ & FilePrefix&" \ ""

            End If
        
        End If
        filen = Dir
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: "C:\TEST\ & Filen" needs to be "C:\TEST\" & Filen and the 2nd "C:\TEST\" & FilePrefix & "\"

Comment: I did as suggested and got no errors until running the code and getting to  the "fsoMoveFile" line and getting "runtime error 424"

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I did solve it in the end—as in it does its job. Instead of to `fso.MoveFile` I used `Name` and it worked for my purpose. Still unclear why `fso.Movefile` didn't work.

The whole code is below if anyone is interested.

```
Sub loopf()
    Dim AcceptedPrefixes As Object
    Set AcceptedPrefixes = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim PrefixRange As Range
    Set PrefixRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("a1:a3")
    
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In PrefixRange.Cells
        If Cell <> "" And Not AcceptedPrefixes.exists(Cell.Value) Then
            AcceptedPrefixes.Add CStr(Cell.Value), 0
        End If
    Next

    Dim Directory As String
    Directory = "C:\TEST\"
    
    Dim fsoFSO
    Set fsoFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Dim filen As Variant
    filen = Dir(Directory)
    While filen <> ""
        Dim FilePrefix As String
        FilePrefix = "" & (Split(filen, "_")(0)) & ""
        
       If Not AcceptedPrefixes.exists(FilePrefix) Then
        Kill Directory & filen
        Else
        If fsoFSO.FolderExists("C:\TEST\" & FilePrefix) Then
        Name "C:\TEST\" & filen As "C:\TEST\" & FilePrefix & "\" & filen
           
      Else: fsoFSO.CreateFolder ("C:\TEST\" & FilePrefix)
      'FSO.MoveFile "C:\TEST\" & filen, "C:\TEST\" & FilePrefix & "\" ---- not working
      Name "C:\TEST\" & filen As "C:\TEST\" & FilePrefix & "\" & filen
      End If
        
        End If
        filen = Dir
    Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`fsoFSO` is not `fso`.

```vb
fsoFSO.CreateFolder ...
fso.MoveFile ...
```

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant

Sub loopf()

    Dim AcceptedPrefixes As Object
    Set AcceptedPrefixes = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim PrefixRange As Range
    Set PrefixRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B2:B368")
    
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In PrefixRange.Cells
        If Cell <> "" And Not AcceptedPrefixes.Exists(Cell.Value) Then
            AcceptedPrefixes.Add CStr(Cell.Value), 0
        End If
    Next

    Dim Directory As String
    Directory = "C:\TEST\"
    Debug.Print "Directory: " & Directory
    
    Dim fsoFSO
    Set fsoFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Dim filen As Variant
    filen = Dir(Directory)
        
    Dim sourceFile As String
    Dim destinationFolder As String
    Dim destinationFile As String
    
    While filen <> ""
    
        Debug.Print
        Debug.Print "filen.....: " & filen
    
        Dim FilePrefix As String
        FilePrefix = "" & (Split(filen, "_")(0)) & ""
        Debug.Print "FilePrefix: " & FilePrefix
        
        sourceFile = Directory & filen
        Debug.Print " sourceFile........: " & sourceFile
        
        If Not AcceptedPrefixes.Exists(FilePrefix) Then
            'Kill sourceFile
            Debug.Print "                Kill " & sourceFile
            
        Else
            destinationFolder = Directory & FilePrefix
            Debug.Print " destinationFolder.: " & destinationFolder
            
            If fsoFSO.FolderExists(destinationFolder) Then
                Debug.Print "  Folder exists....: " & destinationFolder
            Else
                fsoFSO.createFolder (destinationFolder)
                Debug.Print "  Folder **created**: " & destinationFolder
            End If
            
            ' Move files to created or existing folder
            destinationFile = destinationFolder & "\" & filen
            Debug.Print "  destinationFile..: " & destinationFile
            
            fsoFSO.MoveFile sourceFile, destinationFile
            Debug.Print "      file moved to: " & destinationFolder
        End If
        
        filen = Dir
        
    Wend
    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print "** Done ** "
    
End Sub
```